# How to find radio button by id in Android?

Tags: android, radio-button, findviewbyid

I have a radio group with radio button in an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

   <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

</RadioGroup>
```

How can I get a radio button by id? I tried:

```
RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_1)
```

But this throws a nullPointerException when I call `setChecked()` method on `btn`. Did I miss something?

Comment: RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call `.findViewById()` on RadioGroup object. If you define radio group id as `radioGroup` you can access individual button like this:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
View radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
```

Other useful function would be `radioGroup.getChildAt(int)`

Answer (score 1):

You're not pointing at either of your Radio Buttons

You need either:

```
RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
```

or

```
RadioButton btn = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
```

Comment: @ToniJoe Can you show us your code in the Java file aswell? The XML that you've provided doesn't really give much away as to what might be wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
RadioGroup rg= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_RadioGroud_Id);
RadioButton rb= rg.findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
```